# flutter dependencies incompatibel

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies

I am using `coingecko_api: any`, and  `flutter_advanced_networkimage: any` dependencies.

When using the `pub get` command, I get an error message telling me they are incompatible. The message states the following:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.15.1.

Because flutter_advanced_networkimage <0.2.5 requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0 or >=2.0.0-dev <2.0.0 and flutter_advanced_networkimage >=0.3.9 depends on http ^0.12.0, flutter_advanced_networkimage <0.2.5-∞ or >=0.3.9 requires http ^0.12.0.
And because flutter_advanced_networkimage >=0.2.5 <0.3.9 depends on http ^0.11.3 and http >=0.2.8+2 <0.11.3+17 requires SDK version <2.0.0, every version of flutter_advanced_networkimage requires http >=0.11.3+17 <0.12.0 or ^0.12.0.
And because http >=0.11.3+17 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0 depends on http_parser >=0.0.1 <4.0.0 and dio >=4.0.0-beta1 depends on http_parser ^4.0.0, flutter_advanced_networkimage is incompatible with dio >=4.0.0-beta1.
Because coingecko_api >=1.0.2 depends on dio ^4.0.4 and coingecko_api <1.0.2 depends on dio ^4.0.0, every version of coingecko_api requires dio ^4.0.0.
Thus, flutter_advanced_networkimage is incompatible with coingecko_api.
So, because crypto_inventment_tracker depends on both flutter_advanced_networkimage any and coingecko_api any, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because crypto_inventment_tracker depends on both flutter_advanced_networkimage any and coingecko_api any, version solving failed.)'
```

I can not seem to find a solution that works with my problem (I have tried most of the 'dependencies are incompatible' solves).

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried running `flutter pub outdated` to check whether you have packages with compatible versions?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have tried both pub outdated and pub upgrade. pub outdated said there are no compatible versions found and recommends using pub upgrade. pub upgrade gives me about the same error message as the one above.

Comment: Then this is a pretty hard situation, you either have to use other packages that are updated, or copy the package locally and make it compatible with newer versions